# Jhipster in Eclipse STS

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jhipster

I created a project 3.6.1 Jhipster(Gradle)
To debug the back-end import the project STS 3.8.1.
From the "Boot Dashboard" tab to run the application.
I get the following error:

```
[2m2016-10-06 14:14:51.306[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m32187[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaMapper': No qualifying bean of type [com.abalia.atletico.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper] found for dependency [com.abalia.atletico.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.abalia.atletico.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper] found for dependency [com.abalia.atletico.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.abalia.atletico.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper] found for dependency [com.abalia.atletico.service.mapper.CategoriaMapper]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

It is a new project with three entities.
If I run the console is doing well, but I need to debug.
Not if I add some plugin or configuration to Eclipse STS

.yo-rc.json:

```
{"generator-jhipster": {
"jhipsterVersion": "3.6.1",
"baseName": "atletico",
"packageName": "com.aaa.bbb",
"packageFolder": "com/aaa/bbb",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "jwt",
"hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
"clusteredHttpSession": "hazelcast",
"websocket": "spring-websocket",
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
"buildTool": "gradle",
"enableSocialSignIn": true,
"jwtSecretKey": "dabb542aa2359c0c77c19bc6aeefc3af1700cec6",
"useSass": true,
"applicationType": "monolith",
"testFrameworks": [
  "gatling",
  "cucumber",
  "protractor"
],
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "es",
"languages": [
  "es",
  "en"
]
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the generated output.

Following [these instructions](https://jhipster.github.io/configuring-ide-eclipse-gradle/), what you need to do is:

> **Add apt generated source folder to build path**
>
> When using buildship gradles default outputfolder is filtered and not visible in your workspace. Therefore you need to remove it from eclipse’s resource filter setting.
>
> - Right click on your project and select Properties
> - Select Resources
> - Remove the entry build
> - Select Java Build Path
> - Click Add Folder...
> - Check the path build/generated/source/apt/main
>
> Make sure the new source folder contains the correctly generated mapper implementations when running JHipster via eclipse.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A couple of notes. First, we don't care about the age of the question here, so if you have a good answer, please post it! You don't need to apologize for answering an old question. Second, it is a reality of the Internet that links eventually rot, and we're building Q&A for the long-term here. So, when you include a link, [you need to also include the essential parts directly in your answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259). I've done that for you here; please use this as a model for future answers. Thanks!